# Make new watermark file while uploading in PHP

Tags: php, file

I'd like to create a new watermarked file next to the image that is being uploaded.
I came up with this code but it doesn't do anything. PHP doesn't return an error. Somebody knows what I did wrong?

```
function watermark_image(){
    $name = basename($_FILES['file_upload']['name']);

    // Load the watermark and the photo to apply the watermark to
    $stamp = imagecreatefrompng('watermarkMQ.png');
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($name);

    // Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
    $marge_right = 0;
    $marge_bottom = 0;
    $sx = imagesx($stamp);
    $sy = imagesy($stamp);

    // Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
    // width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
    imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

    // Save and free memory
    imagejpeg($im, 'wm_' . $name);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got multiple mistakes:

```
$name = basename($_FILES['file_upload']['name']);
                                       ^^^^^^^^
```

That parameter is the name of the file on the USER's machine. The file that was uploaded to your server is actually in `['tmp_name']`.

You then fail to check for success - PHP won't "return errors". But the GD functions **DO** return boolean false on failure, which you aren't looking for:

```
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($name);
if ($im === false) {
   die("Failed to open $name");
}
```

Never EVER assume an operation dealing with an external resource succeeded. Always assume failure, check for that failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. You taught me how to code better in PHP. I have been coding PHP for 3 weeks now. I do get an error now but it's the "Failed to open" error and it randomly generates a code? :(

(I echoed $name to see what it gets and now I see it randomly generates a code) I need to have the uploaded file name